# The number of placement of $n$ pieces on the chessboard of $n\times n$, such that the piece $k$ cannot be placed in the $k$-th row nor $k$-th column

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, inclusion-exclusion, chessboard

Considering the chessboard of $n\times n$, we now want to put n pieces $1,2,\cdots, n$ on this chessboard, and satisfy that the piece $k$ cannot be placed in the $k$-th row nor $k$-th column, and each grid can only place one piece at most. How many kinds of placement are there?

I calculate the answer with inclusion-exclusion principle

the Mathematica code is:

```
glist = RecurrenceTable[{g[
       i] == (2 n - 1) g[i - 1] + (-2 i + 2) g[i - 2], 
     g[2] == 4 n^2 - 4 n - 1, g[1] == 2 n - 1}, g, {i, 1, 10}] // 
   FullSimplify // Expand
answer[n_] := 
 n!*Binomial[n^2, n] + 
  Sum[(-1)^i*Binomial[n, i]*(g /. {g -> glist[[i]]})*
    Binomial[(n^2 - i), (n - i)]*(n - i)!, {i, 1, n}]
Table[answer[i] /. {n -> i}, {i, 1, 10}]
```

$$
\{0,1,52,4737,718656,162509785,51209676372,21445634148225,11519808468594976,7721569549966334481\}
$$

---

Someone says this question can also be solved with generating function.
$$
n ! \cdot\left[x^n\right](1+x)^{n^2} \cdot \exp \left(\frac{-2 n x}{1+x}+\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}\right)
$$

the following mma code verified the correctness of the formula.

```
Flatten@Table[
  i!*SeriesCoefficient[(1 + x)^{n^2}*
      Exp[-2 n*x/(1 + x) + x/((1 + x)^2)], {x, 0, i}] /. {n -> i}, {i,
    1, 10}]
```

The key word of this approach is probably:

the inclusion-exclusion principle, the Mobius equation/Mobius inversion of [partition lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Refinement_of_partitions), [Weisner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weisner%27s_method).

**My question is: what are the detailed steps of this approach?**

Comment: "Someone says this question can also be solved with generating function." Who is someone? Where did they say?

Comment: I found this question at [ZhiHu](https://www.zhihu.com/question/452651947), a Chinese Q&A site like Quora.